# Stopping Repetition in Data set

Tags: vb.net

So I have Some textBoxes, On a click of a button Apply I save the values of those textboxes and comboboxes in a Data set. What I'm unalble to do is that I can't stop the repetition of a field PaymentType.
Only One type of Payment should be added.

```
Protected Sub lnksaveDetail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnksaveDetail.Click

        Dim dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails As DataSet

        dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails = Session("dataset")

        Dim row As DataRow
        row = dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).NewRow
        row(0) = cboPaymentType.SelectedItem.Text
        row(1) = txtPaid.Text
        row(2) = txtDiscountAmount.Text
        row(3) = 0
        row(4) = cboPaymentType.SelectedValue
        row(5) = txtTotalPayable.Text
        row(6) = 0

        dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
        gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.DataSource = dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails.Tables(0).DefaultView
        gvPlotFilePaymentVouCherDetail.DataBind()
        Session("dataset") = dsPlotFilePaymentVoucherDetails
End Sub
```

Comment: please provide the code of this population method

Comment: how do i edit the Question here ?

Comment: click on edit... then click on the code tag and paste your code there

Comment: here you go @KeithMifsud

Comment: so you want the user to be able to select a payment type the first time and then it gets locked to one value?